# Unable to create new remote session with desired capabilities

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-android

I want to do parallel execution on two devices by using selenium grid. Everything has been done smoothly right from established the JSON, Run Appium Desktop for Each Device.

**Connection established with appium**:

```
public class ApplicationHandling {

public static AndroidDriver driver;
public static ExtentTest test;
public static ExtentReports extent;
//public static boolean waitForPresenceOfElelment;
public static ConfigFileReader cfg;

public  ApplicationHandling()
{
    cfg = new ConfigFileReader();
    System.out.println("Inside application handling constructor");
    Date date=new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatFolder = new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yyyy");
    File ResultDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"/FrameworkReports/"+dateFormatFolder.format(date));
    System.out.println(ResultDir);
    // Defining Directory/Folder Name
    if (!ResultDir.exists()){  // Checks that Directory/Folder Doesn't Exists!
        ResultDir.mkdir();
    }
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MMM_yyyy_hh_mm_ssaa");
    extent=new ExtentReports(ResultDir +"/" +"Report"+""+dateFormat.format(date)+".html",false);
}

public static RemoteWebDriver getInstance()
{
    System.out.println("remote webdriver");
    return driver;
}

@Parameters({"device","version"})
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public static void setUp(String device,String version) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

    cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    cap.setCapability("deviceName", device);
    cap.setCapability("noReset", true);
    cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION,version);
    cap.setCapability("automationName", cfg.getAutomationName());
    cap.setCapability ("appPackage", cfg.getAppPackage());
    cap.setCapability ("appActivity", cfg.getAppActivity());

    System.out.println("Before Suite Execution started");
    System.out.println("Driver:"+driver);
    System.out.println("URL:"+cfg.getApplicationUrl());
    System.out.println("cap: "+cap);

    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(cfg.getApplicationUrl()), cap);
    System.out.println(driver);
}
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "deviceName": "Redmi",
      "platformName": "Windows",
      "browserName":"Android",
      "platformVersion": "7.0",
      "maxInstances": 1
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub",
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 4723
    "maxSession": 1,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": "4444",
    "hubHost": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

**Testng.xml**

```
<test name="test_redmi">
    <parameter name="device" value="Redmi"/>
    <parameter name="version" value="7.0"/>
    <classes>
        <class name="Tests.LoginTest">
             <methods>
                 <include name="loginOTP"/>
             </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
```

**Error Log**

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
>
> org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{appPackage="com.amhi.healthjinn", appActivity="com.amhi.healthjinn.MainActivity", noReset=true, automationName=uiautomator2, platformName=Android, deviceName=Moto E, version=7.1.2}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
>   Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700'

-> It gives me the error where I create an instance of driver.

Comment: can you share this `ApplicationHandling` class code also? In this line, it is showing `capabilities = Capabilities [{}] ` empty capabilities. May be something wrong with an initializations

Comment: can you post the appium server log?

Comment: on the appium, no logs have been generated. It shows that appium successfully registered with grid. the main activity of the app is not called

Comment: Appium log:  [Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.9.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   port: 5001
[Appium]   bootstrapPort: 4725
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true

Comment: nodeconfig: C:\Users\ab.chauhan\AndroidStudioProjects\grid_Server\device2.json
[Appium] Starting auto register thread for grid. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:5001
[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/status
[HTTP] {}
[MJSONWP] Calling AppiumDriver.getStatus() with args: []
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.getStatus() result: {"build":{"version":"1.9.0"}}
[HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/status 200 132 ms - 67
[HTTP] 
[Appium] Appium successfully registered with the grid on http://10.10.23.99:4444

Answer (score 0):

I recently switched from Appium Desktop to Appium Studio, as they support parallel execution, and have plugins for setting up frameworks in different languages like Java, C#, Ruby and so on.
Read [this](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TDB/SeeTestAutomation-+Parallel+Execution) documentation for more on parallel execution.